# How should one handle this simple, instantly self-answered question?

Tags: discussion, instant-self-answer

How should one handle questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70156414/highlight-the-text-when-clicking-on-a-p-autocomplete-angular-primeng)?

They are pretty basic and could be answered after a quick Google search or by reading the official documentation and then end up being immediately answered by the OP themself.

Should they just be left as they are or do they require any actions?

Edit according to the request in comments to include an exmample:

**Question:**

> How do you get the value of a referneced text-field like `<TextField ref='myTextField'/>`?

**Answer:**

> You can use `this.refs.myTextField.input.value` to get the value.

Comment: _They are pretty basic, could be answered after a quick google search or by reading the official docs_ These arent close reasons. If there is a duplicate in SO, then it could be closed as a duplicate. Upvote/Downvote is really up to the user.

Comment: Just like any other question / answer. Is the question on-topic or suitable, or not? Is it a duplicate? Is the answer an actual answer? Etc. Immediately self-answering questions is supported by SO and there is nothing wrong with it in itself.

Comment: Though I know nothing about the technologies tagged, I expect there is a duplicate out there for such a question. VTC/Flag is as a duplicate of that.

Comment: It's a pretty simple duplicate. I cast the last (of 3) close-votes, but apparently that wasn't enough for the dupe banner.

Comment: It also has a re-open vote now...

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, I find that is a bit of a weakness with duplicates - two non-dupe votes and one dupe means there is no consensus, so it's not marked as a duplicate. Unless the final vote comes from a dupe hammer.

Comment: @SurajRao & Jeanne: Thx for the clarification - At the time I reviewed the OP the self-answer wasn't present and I VTC'd for _'Needs debugging details'_ since there was no mvce or any attempt made to solve it.

Comment: @VLAZ Pls see my comment in regards to the consensus issue ( two non-dupe votes) above..

Comment: Oh well, the author deleted it...

Comment: Could the question be edited with an example of what the question was? So that this question exists for the posterity?

Comment: @Laif I'll edit the question to include an example similar to the question and answer..

Comment: Before being deleted (with two reopen votes and a +2/-5 (total -3) score), it was closed as *"needs details or clarity"* and a proposed duplicate in comments (as a result of a close vote?) of *[Angular 2 select text on specific input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291655/)*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Evaluate the question just like you would do with any other question. Is it clear? Does the answer make sense? The author wanted to share the knowledge and asked a pretty clear question. I don't think any close reason applies apart from duplicate closure.

If the question is so simple that the answer can already be found on Stack Overflow then vote to close as a duplicate.

If you think the question and answer is actually useful then upvote it. If you think it's not useful then you can downvote.

I don't see what other actions could be taken on this valid question.

In this case, the author self-deleted as they realized it was an obvious duplicate.

Comment: My normal routine is to check first wether the OP actually provided a detailed question with an attempt to solve the problem (including code, a minimal example and possible errors encountered) and then check for dupes. I guess I should change the order of my routine to  1. check for dupes and 2. check if any other VTC-reasons apply (obviously spam excluded from this routine). Would you agree or can you provide me with a better strategy?

Comment: @iLuvLogix In order to look for dupes, you have to make sure the question is on-topic and clear. Only then you can look for potential dupes.

Comment: Ok - so would you say that my  'Needs debugging details'-VTC was applicable when the immediately provided self-answer wasn't present at the time I reviewed that question?

Comment: @iLuvLogix Definitely not. The question was not a debugging question. It doesn't require MCVE or debugging details. This was a how-to question.

Comment: Got you - if the question was on-topic and clear (due to the how-to nature of it) I could have immediatly checked for dupes.. Thx for clarifiying!